# What's the Proper way to read/pass querystring values to a view in MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

my url is working correctly as i can step into the controls correct method but..how am I to read the state name from the url into the view?

My url: http://localhost:10860/Listings/Arizona/page1

My view:

>" %>

```
<h2>Test BY STATE</h2>

 <%
     LOTW.Models.ListingRepository dr = new LOTW.Models.ListingRepository();
     ListViewListings.DataSource = dr.GetByStateName(???? I can hard code "Arizona" and this works???????); // how do i grab the 'Arizona' from the url? Reqquest.Querystring doesn't work?
     ListViewListings.DataBind();
    %>

 <%--Define the table headers to work with the tablesorter--%>
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListViewListings">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="ListViewListings" class="tablesorter">
                <thead>
                    <tr>.....
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid having that much code in your View.  Why not use your controller to read the Querystring and pass the value to the controller with ViewData.

Controller

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
   ''# however you access your repository
   ViewData("StateName") = dr.GetByStateName(Request.QueryString("TheState"))
End Function
```

Markup

```
<% For Each item In ViewData("StateName") %>
       <li><%: item.State %></li>
<% Next%>
```

Comment: Ya I like your idea better....than what I just found to make it work...instead of request.querystring[....] ...it's RouteData.Values["stateName"].ToString()...but I'll put it in the controller instead...thanks x 10

Comment: try as best as you can to NOT use `<asp: ... />` controls in your markup.  Instead try and embrace the truly stateless nature of MVC and use as much generic HTML as possible. I have yet to find any reason to use `DataSources` or `<asp: ... />` controls in my Views.

Answer (score 0):

The bit below does not really belong in the view

```
<%
 LOTW.Models.ListingRepository dr = new LOTW.Models.ListingRepository();
 ListViewListings.DataSource = dr.GetByStateName(???? I can hard code "Arizona" and this works???????); // how do i grab the 'Arizona' from the url? Reqquest.Querystring doesn't work?
 ListViewListings.DataBind();
%>
```

Some of it should really should be in the controller action method.

```
class HomeController {
 public ActionResult Index(string state) {
   LOTW.Models.ListingRepository dr = new LOTW.Models.ListingRepository();
   var list = dr.GetByStateName(state); // how do i grab the 'Arizona' from the url? Reqquest.Querystring doesn't work?

   return View(list);
 }
}
```

Parameter `state` in the action method will come from the URL. Depending on how you set up your routes, it would either be mysite.com/home/NY or mysite.com/home/?state=NY

Then in the view:

```
<%
 ListViewListings.DataSource = Model;
 ListViewListings.DataBind();
%>
```